# Print out all necessary for compilation files

Tags: makefile

I have bunch of Make files though directory hierarchy, some of them define C (CPP) and H files to use in compilations, some of them not, that are not adds to `CPFLAFS -I../../SomeDir1 -I../SomeDir2/SomeDir2/Inc.` etc.

Some of the Make files are called via `make -C PATH Target` .

The thing is hierarchy of sources grew for years and covers different projects and target platforms.
Now there are no people left in the company who remember "why that" and there is not enough documentation left.

The question: is there way to know particular sources and header files used to build the final target "all" ?

Thank you

Comment: Turn on the verbose mode when you executing make command. Like `make V=1 <target>`

Comment: If the makefiles are written badly enough, there may be no easy way to find out which source and header files are used; you must work your way through it line by line. And remember that a file that is *used* may not be *necessary.*

Comment: @Santosh, what did you mean under V=1? I do not have such variables in Make files.

Comment: @KSI : V=1 means enable verbose mode. Print all the commands that is been executed

Comment: @Santosh `V=1` is a feature that most (all?) `make` do not support. It looks like this rather is a feature of certain `Makefile`s, not `make` in general. `make` prints the commands it executes by default (command echo), and option `-s` or prefix `@` would disable the command echo. Printing the commands is only a partial solution for the question asked, because with the commands I would only come to know about the sources, but not the header files.

Comment: @ChristianHujer Yes, I agree with you. Not all `Makefile's` support this. This is a feature of Linux kernel. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways, I know of two. Both require that you run `make all`, and before that remove all generated files so every file in question would actually be rebuilt (usually `make clean`).

#### Using `strace`

If `strace` is available, you can find the files by tracing and analyzing the system calls.
You can do it like this:

```
$ strace -f -o trace make all
$ grep 'open.*\.[ch]"' trace | grep -v 'open("/\(tmp\|usr\)' | sed -e 's/.*open("//' -e 's/".*//' | sort -u
```

#### Using Dependency Files (doesn't work with all compilers)

If your compiler can generate dependency files (i.e. `gcc`, `armcc`), you can analyze the dependency files. Make sure that dependency files are generated by putting the corresponding option in your `CFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS`. For `gcc`, this would be `-MMD`. If Makefiles are written nicely, you can set `CPPFLAGS` on the command line, I will use this example here.

```
$ make all CPPFLAGS+=-MMD
$ find -name "*.d" -exec cat {} \; | sed -e 's/[:\\]//' -e 's/ /\n/g' | grep '\.[ch]$' | sort -u
```

Comment: (why I did not re-read gcc man) Christian Hujer, does it make sence to use -save-temps instead or in addition to -MMD?

Comment: "instead" - no, you wanted to know which header files are read during the build process, didn't you? "in addition" - if you like to, why not, although it will simply generate intermediate preprocessed C files (.i), assembler files (.s), and in case something would be directly linked, intermediate object files (.o). It might be useful in general, for debugging purposes, out of curiosity or whatsoever, but not for the problem finding out which C Source and Header files are actually read for `make all` - which is how I understood your question.

Comment: this is I was looking for. thank you  for the clarifications. unfortunately some Makefile's written badly, so I would need to add that options directly.